# Why does symantec quarantine the latest version of Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I was able to download doxygen 1.8.13-setup.exe for windows.  However when I download the latest version, Symantec states that there is strong evidence that doxygen-1.8.14-setup.exe is untrustworthy.  First, is anyone else having problems with the latest installer that was produced in December of 2017?  Something is different about it that causes the antivirus program to quarantine it.  I've never had any problems like that with previous versions of doxygen.

Here is the link where I found the setup program.  I also tried downloading directly from the doxygen website, and the result was the same.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/
http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html

Comment: I've noticed that the setup for 1.8.14 is significantly larger too (45 MB vs 25 MB for the previous version).  I didn't see any release notes yet to see what might have changed in the latest version.  Where can I find that type of information?

Comment: For release notes: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/changelog.html
most of those are essentially the commit texts from the repo
https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen

Comment: I upgrade a number of dependent packages such as libclang, which is probably explaining the size increase. I don't know why this virus scanner decide to flag doxygen's installer. See also https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/1574b08bb565998d1032e7e7a345fe15a9c44410c87f09528eec5fe50f3fcad0/detection

Comment: I've regenerated the installer .exe using the latest version of inno-setup. At least now all virus scanners at virustotal report green. Can you please re-download and check for if this also gets rid of the symantec quarantine?

Comment: Ok.  I was able to install it successfully that time.  Thank you.